On Jenkins, how can we hide the Jetty version in response headers?
When we hit "http://JENKINSIP:8080/loginError" in the response header Server: jetty(10.0.20). how can hide version from header.
JEKINS-: Version 2.452.2 and 2.375.
JAVA-: openjdk 11.0.23 2024-04-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04.2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04.2, mixed mode, sharing)
Ubuntu version 20.04lts.

Why? Security through obscurity is not recommended
Since 2008, NIST SP 800-123 Guide to General Server Security, chapter 2.4, has advised:

When addressing server security issues, it is an excellent idea to keep in mind the following general information security principles: - -

Open Design — System security should not depend on the secrecy of the implementation or its components.


Hiding this single information does not really help, because:

It would be easy to indirectly guess the version by fingerprinting its artifacts, e.g., the static JavaScript and CSS files it is serving.
Automated attacks do not really care about checking the version. It is more efficient to just launch the exploit and move on, if it did not work for a reason or another; updated version, web application firewall (WAF) blocking the request, hardened configuration...

If you want to take a single action it would not be hiding the version, but updating regularly or automating the security updates.
I still want to do it
Jenkins does not seem to have any configuration options for hiding the version information.
You could place a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of the site. On the reverse proxy you can:

Remove any headers you do not want to reveal.
Allow access to any resources (including static) after authentication.
Use the reverse proxy as a WAF denying potentially harmful requests.

